# Why my unit tests are failing when using $location and $route in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, routes, location, karma-jasmine

I have all my unit tests failing after adding $location and $route to my controllers. I tried to mock them following a few answers found online but it doesn't seem to change anything.

Controllers:

```
 myAppModule.controller('addUserCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$location',
      function ($scope, $http, $location) {
        $scope.addNewUser = function(user){
          $http.post('url/users', user);
          $location.path('/')
        }
      }
    ]);

myAppModule.controller('usersCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$route',
  function ($scope, $http, $route) {
    $http.get('url/users').success(function(data){
      $scope.users = data;
    })

    $scope.delete = function(id){
      $http.delete('url/users/' + id).success(function(){
        $route.reload();
      })
    }
  }
]);
```

Test setup for addUserCtrl:

```
describe('addUserCtrl controller', function(){

  beforeEach(module('myAppModule'));

  var scope, ctrl, $httpBackend;

  var user = [
    {
      "username": "Zoltan",
      "email": "Zoltan@Z.com"
    }
  ]

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$httpBackend_, $rootScope, $controller) {
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    $httpBackend.expectPOST('url/users', user).
    respond(200, 'Done');
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    ctrl = $controller('addUserCtrl', { $scope: scope });
  }));

some test here

})
```

Test setup for usersCtrl:

```
    describe('UsersCtrl', function(){

      beforeEach(module('myAppModule'));

      var scope, ctrl, $httpBackend;

      var users = [
        {
          "username": "Zoltan",
          "email": "Zoltan@Z.com",
          "id": 1
        },
        {
          "username": "Aria123",
          "email": "aria@aria.com",
          "id": 2
        }
      ]

      beforeEach(inject(function(_$httpBackend_, $rootScope, $controller) {
       $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
       $httpBackend.expectGET('url/users').respond(users);
       scope = $rootScope.$new();
       ctrl = $controller('usersCtrl', { $scope:scope });
     }));

some test here

   })
```

I can write anything in the tests and they are failing with this error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
        at $LocationProvider.$get (/home/elena/projects/myAppInAngularJS/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:11305:34)
```

Comment: First step, you need to inject `$location` and `$route` a la `$controller`